# onload is not getting fired for the reference of window.load in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, pdf, jquery-plugins

i am opening a `PDF`link in a new window, while opening the `PDF` i want to set the title of the new tab as say "your title" and the code follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var mapWin = window.open('${pdfUrl}');
    mapWin.onload = function(){
        alert("on load");
        console.log("document on load......")
        setTimeout(function(){
         $(mapWin.document).find('html').append('<head><title>your title</title></head>');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

the "pdfUrl" is a service call which streams the `PDF`.
i am getting the alert in Chrome and the title of the new tab is also getting set as required. but in IE i am not able to set the title and i am not even getting the alert which is inside onload function.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: i am using IE11

Comment: probably using different pdf rendering methods in each browser. For example Adobe reader vs chrome using jspdf.js What are the IE settings for pdf display?

Comment: Could you try this? http://pastie.org/pastes/10987160/text (I also agree with @charlietfl in that it could be PDF related)

Comment: @charlietfl the odf rendering is working fine, but i am calling onload event and inside it i am changing the Tab title. which works fine in chrome

Comment: That's not what I am asking. Browsers can use outside apps to render pdf and is dependent on user settings. PDF's themselves are not html documents

Comment: @AndreasElia i tried the solution pastie.org/pastes/10987160/text and it is not working in IE.